# L3 cache miss when iterating over small amount data

Tags: performance, amd, cpu-cache

I'm optimizing a critical part of my program. the algorithm basicly iterating part of rows of a matrix(M) and apply `H += alpha * M[x]`

the matrix(M) is 8MB in size and i'm only iterating first quarter rows(2MB). it should completly fit in L3 cache. but I still got large number of L3 miss in perf which is propotional to the number of iterations(e.g. `6*max_iter`)

So my question is why the L3 cache miss happens and how can i avoid this?

my CPU is AMD epyc 9654 which should be in Zen4 architecture and has 32MB L3 cache per CCX. 96 cores and I disabled hyperthreading.

I also did some system-level tunning that:

```
# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt2)/vmlinuz-4.18.0-477.27.1.el8_8.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/rhel-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=rhel/root rhgb quiet hugepagesz=1G hugepages=4 processor.max_cstate=0 rcu_nocbs=88-95 nohz=on nohz_full=88-95 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 mce=ignore_ce nmi_watchdog=0 transparent_hugepage=never pcie_aspm=performance audit=0 nosoftlockup iommu=off intel_iommu=off nopti nospec_store_bypass_disable nospectre_v2 nospectre_v1 noibrs noibpb nopti lltf=off nospec_store_bypass_disable no_stf_barrier mds=off mitigations=off noht pcie_port_pm=off ipv6.disable=1 ipmi_si.force_kipmid=0 selinux=0 intel_pstat=disable isolcpus=88-95
```

```
# perf stat -C 88 -e l3_lookup_state.l3_miss,cache-misses,cs,L1-icache-load-misses taskset -c 88 ./a.out 1 1024 150000

 Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 88':

            883961      l3_lookup_state.l3_miss
          44439939      cache-misses
                10      cs
             49068      L1-icache-load-misses

       3.967808823 seconds time elapsed

# perf stat -C 88 -e l3_lookup_state.l3_miss,cache-misses,cs,L1-icache-load-misses taskset -c 88 ./a.out 1 1024 1500000

 Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 88':

           8271822      l3_lookup_state.l3_miss
         440835405      cache-misses
                12      cs
            474544      L1-icache-load-misses

      38.803435718 seconds time elapsed
```

here's the latest *simplified* code

```
static inline void add(double *H, double diff, double *XX, ssize_t cnt) {
  __m256d fac = _mm256_set1_pd(diff);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; i += 32) {
    __m256d h1 = _mm256_load_pd(H + 0);
    __m256d h2 = _mm256_load_pd(H + 4);
    __m256d h3 = _mm256_load_pd(H + 8);
    __m256d h4 = _mm256_load_pd(H + 12);

    __m256d x1 = _mm256_load_pd(XX + 0);
    __m256d x2 = _mm256_load_pd(XX + 4);
    __m256d x3 = _mm256_load_pd(XX + 8);
    __m256d x4 = _mm256_load_pd(XX + 12);

    __m256d h5 = _mm256_load_pd(H + 16);
    __m256d h6 = _mm256_load_pd(H + 20);
    __m256d h7 = _mm256_load_pd(H + 24);
    __m256d h8 = _mm256_load_pd(H + 28);

    __m256d x5 = _mm256_load_pd(XX + 16);
    __m256d x6 = _mm256_load_pd(XX + 20);
    __m256d x7 = _mm256_load_pd(XX + 24);
    __m256d x8 = _mm256_load_pd(XX + 28);

    _mm256_store_pd(H + 0, _mm256_fmadd_pd(fac, x1, h1));
    _mm256_store_pd(H + 4, _mm256_fmadd_pd(fac, x2, h2));
    _mm256_store_pd(H + 8, _mm256_fmadd_pd(fac, x3, h3));
    _mm256_store_pd(H + 12, _mm256_fmadd_pd(fac, x4, h4));

    _mm256_store_pd(H + 16, _mm256_fmadd_pd(fac, x5, h5));
    _mm256_store_pd(H + 20, _mm256_fmadd_pd(fac, x6, h6));
    _mm256_store_pd(H + 24, _mm256_fmadd_pd(fac, x7, h7));
    _mm256_store_pd(H + 28, _mm256_fmadd_pd(fac, x8, h8));

    H += 32;
    XX += 32;
  }
}

void test(size_t max_iter, size_t N, double *H, double *XX, double alpha) {
  for (size_t iter = 0; iter < max_iter; iter++) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < N / 4; x++) {
      double *curXX = XX + x * N;
      add(H, alpha, curXX, N);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  static size_t N = std::stoul(argv[1]);
  static size_t max_iter = std::stoul(argv[2]);
  double *DATA = (double *)mmap(nullptr, N * (N + 1) * sizeof(double), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                              MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_HUGETLB |
                                  ((30 & MAP_HUGE_MASK) << MAP_HUGE_SHIFT),
                              -1, 0);
  if ((double *)-1 == DATA) {
    perror("failied to mmap: ");
    return -1;
  }

  mlock(DATA, N * (N + 1) * sizeof(double));
  test(max_iter, N, DATA, DATA + N, 3.14);
}
```

More perf data as @Jérôme Richard suggested

```
# perf stat -e ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_far,ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_near,ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_all,ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.all,ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.dram_io_near,ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.dram_io_far,cache-misses  -C 8 .
/a.out 1 1920 30000
T = 1, N = 1920
BLOCK_SIZE = 29568000
tid: 0. XX = 0x7f1cc0012c00
tid:0 elapsed: 2742097495ns

 Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 8':

              5273      ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_far                                     (85.71%)
           1522996      ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_near                                     (85.71%)
           1644633      ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_all                                     (85.71%)
         142883985      ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.all                                         (85.71%)
            318971      ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.dram_io_near                                     (85.71%)
               561      ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.dram_io_far                                     (85.72%)
          36719500      cache-misses                                                  (85.72%)

       2.925452367 seconds time elapsed

# perf stat -e ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_far,ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_near,ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_all,ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.all,ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.dram_io_near,ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.dram_io_far,cache-misses  -C 8 ./a.out 1 1920 60000
T = 1, N = 1920
BLOCK_SIZE = 29568000
tid: 0. XX = 0x7f68c0012c00
tid:0 elapsed: 5485570742ns

 Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 8':

              7406      ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_far                                     (85.71%)
           3011325      ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_near                                     (85.71%)
           2979624      ls_any_fills_from_sys.dram_io_all                                     (85.71%)
         280931278      ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.all                                         (85.71%)
            560910      ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.dram_io_near                                     (85.71%)
              1490      ls_hw_pf_dc_fills.dram_io_far                                     (85.72%)
          72840549      cache-misses                                                  (85.71%)

       5.669287832 seconds time elapsed
```

Comment: While the numbers seems huge at first glance, they are not so compared to the computation. `l3_lookup_state.l3_miss` is 6 miss/iteration and `cache-misses` is 815 miss/iteration, that is, <2.5% of the L3 cache line accesses. The L3 is not perfect and there are other running applications on the machine that can cause context switches. Can you measure also the number of context-switches? I assume it to be small but a miss rate of 2.5% is rather small too. I think there are specific counters to see what kind of miss it is (like on Intel). Can you check if this is conflict-misses?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I checked context-switch.(updated the question). it seems very small since I've tweaked many of system parameters. I isolated cpu from schedular and banned irq from the core running the test. the only thing I coundn't manage is LocalTimerInterrupts which should be trigger 1/sec.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I didn't find metrics related cache miss reason even on intel platform. could this be collected by perf or need to use vendor provided software?

Comment: Thank you for the additional informations. Indeed for the context-switches. Strange for `perf`, maybe it is not provided by AMD (yet), but it would be surprising. AFAIK, `perf` either support only system-related performance events when hardware ones are not accessible (eg. VM or bad `perf` implem), or support all available (hardware+software) counters. I am not very familiar with AMD CPU though. Can you share the result of `perf list`?

Comment: @JérômeRichard please check the perf list results here: https://kvtrading-corp-third-party-releases.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/perf-list-amd-9654.txt and https://kvtrading-corp-third-party-releases.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/perf-list-intel-8458.txt

Comment: The Intel one is not very useful as it does not include hardware events. This is certainly because the Intel machine is not a bare metal machine but a VM or `perf` implem is not the right one (generic implem).

Comment: Regarding the AMD machine, there is not much useful information about the L3 indeed. AFAIK, `cache-misses` is supposed to measure LLC misses (at least is does on Intel and it should be generic), and as opposed to `l3_lookup_state.l3_miss`, it includes the prefetched cache-lines. I cannot explain the `6 miss/iter` yet but, I think it is not very important since the number of miss is very small for this event. `cache-misses` is more critical. If the problem is prefetching, then I expect the `l2_pf_miss_l2_l3` and `ls_hw_pf_dc_fills` event groups to be useful.

Comment: `ls_any_fills_from_sys` might be useful to check if `cache-misses` is reliable and cache lines are filled from the DRAM as expected. Sad AMD does not have an IMC throughput hardware event like Intel.

Comment: @JérômeRichard it's weird that intel one is a bare metal machine and has the same version of rhel 8.5. any other ideas to get the hardware counters?

Comment: I advise you to check the implementation of perf on the target machine. Note the implementations are AFAIK dependent of the hardware. This is why generic implementations fail to provide a list having hardware performance counters (typically used in VM/containers hence my comment). You can generally get the implementation based on packages or compile it yourself (more cumbersome). VTune uses its own solution so it should not be affected by this. AFAIK there is an independent Intel tool to get the list on github but I do not remember which one (maybe PCM or PMU-tools).

Comment: Ha, it seems to be this one : https://github.com/intel/perfmon (and https://perfmon-events.intel.com/ for the website having the list based on the architecture -- sad its certificate is obsolete).